# MySQL Window function calculates percentage

Tags: mysql, window

Hi I used MySQL Window function to calculate each product's profit percentage over total profit. However, it doesn't work as I expected.

The data: Table A

```
total   Profit      productCode productName
5554.56 S10_1949    1952        Alpine Renault 1300
5473.71 S12_4675    1969        Dodge Charger
5078.35 S12_1108    2001        Ferrari Enzo
4475    S12_1099    1968        Ford Mustang
```

My code

```
select A.totalProfit, 
A.totalProfit/sum(A.totalProfit) over (PARTITION BY A.totalProfit) as profitPercent, 
A.productCode, A.productName
from A;
```

The output I got, which profitPercent was not calculated correctly

```
totalProfit profitPercent   productCode productName
5554.56     1               S10_1949    1952 Alpine Renault 1300
5473.71     1               S12_4675    1969 Dodge Charger
5078.35     1               S12_1108    2001 Ferrari Enzo
4475        1               S12_1099    1968 Ford Mustang
```

Expected output

```
totalProfit profitPercent   productCode productName
5554.56     0.26987963      S10_1949    1952 Alpine Renault 1300
5473.71     0.265951368     S12_4675    1969 Dodge Charger
5078.35     0.246741996     S12_1108    2001 Ferrari Enzo
4475        0.217427005     S12_1099    1968 Ford Mustang
```

Any suggestion about my code ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the `PARTITION` from your window function:

```
SELECT
    A.totalProfit, 
    A.totalProfit / SUM(A.totalProfit) OVER () AS profitPercent,
    A.productCode,
    A.productName
FROM A;
```

[image]

### Demo

In this case, you want to take the sum of the profit over the entire table, so there should be no partition in your call to `SUM()`.  It is perfectly legal for `OVER` to have no input, and in that case it just means no partition, which defaults to include the entire table.

Comment: Thank you! I think i misunderstood the usage of partition